# text-align:center for select not working in safari and IE

Tags: select, text, center

[image]`text-align:center` for  `select` is not working in safari and IE, I have tried bellow code:

```
text-align:center;text-align-last: center
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? can you post a screenshot so we can see what's going on?

Comment: a CSS property should end with a `;`, not a `,`.

Comment: @Michael: I mean above properties work only for firefox and chrome those wont work on IE and safari for select tag

Comment: @Takit Isy: mistakenly gave comma here.